# Return Page Title of certain Pages

Tags: javascript, variables, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Could anyone help me with some javascript to return the page title of only certain pages on our site?

I want to use this within a custom javascript variable in Google Tag Manager to fire a different tag.

I use the following regex to ensure that I get only the pages in question - (^/play/\w+)

Comment: Start here http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your are using GTM, create a javascript variable named e.g. "Title" and in the "global variable name" enter document.title.

Use your regex on that variable in the trigger that fires your tag to trigger only when the condition is met.

Answer (score -1):

Like Eike says,
the best form is to create a javascript variable where you stock up the title.

In GTM you must create a trigger where you specify the pages where you want to see the title.

For example, your trigger could be like this:

[image: trigger example]